# Java: Code structure & class naming of primitive-type variants - best practices

Tags: java, class, naming-conventions, primitive-types

Recently, I have been writing many classes which have, apart from generic variant, some primitive variants, for example `Foo<T>`, `IntFoo`, `DoubleFoo` etc. First, I used to put every variant in separate files but I soon found out that the package content has become unreadable due to large number of classes with similar names. On the other hand, putting those in a separate package often results in a loss of cohesion and extra dependencies between packages.

In the meanwhile, I have come to the idea to have the following structure:

```
public class Foo {
    public static class TypeFoo<T> { ... }
    public static class IntFoo { ... }
    public static class DoubleFoo { ... }
    ...
}
```

or

```
public class Foo {
    public static class Type<T> { ... }
    public static class Int { ... }
    public static class Double { ... }
}
```

I am interested in two things:

1. Does any of these two approaches result in greater overhead when using only one inner class (e.g. int-variant of the class), compared to one-class-per-file approach? Does this overhead, if any, applies when there are inner interfaces instead?
2. Which of these two approaches is better, if any, or if none is good, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inner classes will be more of a pain in the long run, in my opinion. if you look at the way Microsoft named their [animation classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608874.aspx), they had the same dilemma that you did. They chose to have tons of different classes, but as a consumer of these I have found that I prefer it to be this way.

to answer your first question, there should be no overhead. When java compiles inner classes it separates them into separate `*.class` files anyway, so in the end the result is the same. During compilation the parser will have to sift through a lot of `Foo.*` references but the extra time would be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Might be completely irrelevant to what you're doing, but you could consider replacing all these classes with a Builder (or otherwise known as [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)) pattern. If these classes implement a generic interface, you shouldn't need to expose them anywhere and can still keep them inside one builder class.

A good example of this would be [MapMaker](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) which probably has zillion different inner classes but the only thing you care about is the `Map` or `ConcurrentMap` instance you get out of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use this pattern here, because the only reason for creating these variants like IntFoo, DoubleFoo etc. is to avoid lots of object allocation when doing arithmetic calculations.

Comment: You could still do it if you churn a lot of primitives inside the inner object and have a method which returns single (boxed) result. Also, if you creating class like IntFoo, you already add overhead, aren't you? Anyway, it's hard for me to elaborate as I don't know the internals well enough.

Comment: Suppose you are implementing a counter for Objects and have a templated class `ObjectCounter<T>` with the method `T getCount(Object o)`. Suppose you have counted the number of occurences of each int from a huge int[] array. Now you want to find out how many each of the numbers between -1000000 and 1000000 appeared in that array. With object/generic return type of the `count` method, this means that many object creations, although it is possible to do this without any allocation (if you had method which returns primitive). This example is just to illustrate my point, not a practical scenario.